# WSALookupService returns all zero bluetooth service class guid

Tags: c++, c, windows, bluetooth

I'm have written a function to query services of all nearby bluetooth device. Everything works fine except that service class id stored in lpServiceClassId of the WSAQUERYSET containing sdp information is always zero. Here is the loop for WSALookupServiceNext:

```
//...
flags = LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_FLUSHCACHE 
| LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RES_SERVICE;
//...

bufferLength1 = sizeof( buffer1 );
pResults      = ( WSAQUERYSET* )&buffer1;
// Next service query
result = WSALookupServiceNext( hLookup2, flags, &bufferLength1, pResults );
if ( result == 0 ) {
    // Populate the service info
    printf( "      ServiceInstanceName: %s\n", pResults->lpszServiceInstanceName );
    printf( "          comment: %s\n", pResults->lpszComment );

    pCSAddr = ( CSADDR_INFO* )pResults->lpcsaBuffer;
    // Extract the sdp info
    if ( pResults->lpBlob ) {
        pBlob = ( BLOB* )pResults->lpBlob;
        if ( !BluetoothSdpEnumAttributes( pBlob->pBlobData, pBlob->cbSize, callback, 0 ) ) {
            printf( "          BluetoothSdpEnumAttributes() failed with error code %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        }
        printf( "          serviceClassID(llu): %llu\n", *pResults->lpServiceClassId );
        printf( "          serviceClassID: %s\n", GUID2CharArray( pResults->lpServiceClassId) );
        SDP_ELEMENT_DATA Element;
        BluetoothSdpGetAttributeValue( pBlob->pBlobData, pBlob->cbSize, SDP_ATTRIB_SERVICE_ID, &Element);
        printf( "          serviceID: %s\n", GUID2CharArray(&Element.data.uuid128));
        pCSAddr->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr;
        SOCKADDR_BTH* SockAddressInfo = ( SOCKADDR_BTH* )pResults->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr;
        printf( "          address: %s\n", BTH_ADDR2CharArray(SockAddressInfo->btAddr)); //%llx turns unsigned long long to hex.
        printf( "          port: %u\n", SockAddressInfo->port );
    }
```

A typical output looks like this:

```
Device Instance Name:EDIFIER TWS5
          Local Device Address: (00:E0:4C:23:99:87) 
          Remote Device Address: (5C:C6:E9:80:3D:82)
          WSASERVICE_NOT_FOUND. Could not find any service on this device.
          Move to next device...
Device Instance Name:EDIFIER TWS5
          WSAAddressToString() for Local Address failed with error code 87
          87: ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
          Remote Device Address: (5C:C6:E9:5A:DD:E3)
      ServiceInstanceName: 
          comment: 
          serviceClassID(llu): 0
          serviceClassID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
          serviceID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000065006C00
          address: 5C:C6:E9:5A:DD:E3
          port: 25
      // ...
      ServiceInstanceName: Hands-Free unit
          comment:
          serviceClassID(llu): 0
          serviceClassID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
          serviceID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000065006C00
          address: 5C:C6:E9:5A:DD:E3
          port: 10
      ServiceInstanceName: 
          comment:
          serviceClassID(llu): 0
          serviceClassID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
          serviceID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000065006C00
          address: 5C:C6:E9:5A:DD:E3
          port: 65279
          WSA_E_NO_MORE. No more device
```

As can be seen, ServiceClassIds in lpServiceClassId are all zeros, and serviceID retrieved by BluetoothSdpGetAttributeValue are also strange fixed value. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: The flags parameter is invalid. It must be something like this: LUP_RES_SERVICE | LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_TYPE | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_COMMENT | LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_FLUSHCACHE; The QuerySet.lpszContext should be set to the device's address. lpServiceClassId must be set to upper protocol UUID (if you want to enumerate all services set it to L2CAP UUID, if you want to check if device has only specific service - set it to specific service's UUID)

Comment: I do not recommend to combine devices inquire and services enumeration. First inquire available devices then query for services from each one.

Comment: Also, parse SDP BLOB manually, do not use BluetoothSdpXXX functions. They don't parse SDP correctly and do not provide all information (especially if SDP is incorrectly formatted).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try using BluetoothSdpEnumerateAttributes instead, and separate device and service query. I have also removed LUP_CONTAINERS from flags, and set lpServiceClassId to L2CAP_PROTOCOL_UUID, but somehow the uuids are still all zeros.

Comment: All the answers can be found by this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin-for-service-discovery  Additionally SDP description can be foun dby this link: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/

Comment: Did you figure out?